# How can I read/parse following text using Clojure?

Tags: parsing, clojure

The structure of Text is like this;

```
Tag001
 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4
 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8
 ...
Tag002
 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4
 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8
 ...
```

Files can have any number of TagXXX things and each Tag can have any number of CSV value lines.

==== PPPS. (Sorry for these stuffs :-)

More improvements; now it takes 1 seconds or so for 31842 lines of data on my atom laptop, which is 7 times faster than original code. However, C version is 20 times faster than this.

```
(defn add-parsed-code [accu code]
  (if (empty? code)
    accu
    (conj accu code)))

(defn add-values [code comps]
  (let [values comps
        old-values (:values code)
        new-values (if old-values
                     (conj old-values values)
                     [values])]
    (assoc code :values new-values)))

(defn read-line-components [file]
  (map (fn [line] (clojure.string/split line #","))
       (with-open [rdr (clojure.java.io/reader file)]
         (doall (line-seq rdr)))))

(defn parse-file [file]
  (let [line-comps (read-line-components file)]
    (loop [line-comps line-comps
           accu []
           curr {}]
      (if line-comps
        (let [comps (first line-comps)]
          (if (= (count comps) 1) ;; code line?
            (recur (next line-comps)
                   (add-parsed-code accu curr)
                   {:code (first comps)})
            (recur (next line-comps)
                   accu
                   (add-values curr comps))))
        (add-parsed-code accu curr)))))
```

==== PPS.

Though I cannot figure out why first one is 10 times faster than second one, instead of
slurp, map and with-open does make reading faster; though whole reading/processing time
does not that reduced (from 7 sec. to 6 sec)

```
(time
 (let [lines (map (fn [line] line)
                  (with-open [rdr (clojure.java.io/reader
                                   "DATA.txt")]
                    (doall (line-seq rdr))))]
   (println (last lines))))

(time (let [lines
            (clojure.string/split-lines
             (slurp "DATA.txt"))]
        (println (last lines))))
```

==== PS.
Skuro's solution did work. But the parsing speed is not that fast so I have to use C-based parser (which reads 400 files in 1~3 secs, whereas clojure does take 1~4 secs for single file; yes file sizes are rather large) for reading and constructing DB and clojure for statistical analysis part only.

Comment: Maybe `REGEX` is suitable.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following parses the above file keeping any values line separated. If that's not what you want you can change the `add-values` function. The parsing state is held in the `curr` variable, while `accu` holds previously parsed tags (i.e. all the lines that appeared before a "TagXXX" was found). It allows for values without a tag:

**UPDATE:** side effect now encapsulated in a dedicated `load-file` function

```
(defn tag? [line]
  (re-matches #"Tag[0-9]*" line))

; potentially unsafe, you might want to change this:
(defn parse-values [line]
  (read-string (str "[" line "]")))

(defn add-parsed-tag [accu tag]
  (if (empty? tag)
      accu
      (conj accu tag)))

(defn add-values [tag line]
  (let [values (parse-values line)
        old-values (:values tag)
        new-values (if old-values
                       (conj old-values values)
                       [values])]
    (assoc tag :values new-values)))

(defn load-file [path]
  (slurp path))

(defn parse-file [file]
  (let [lines (clojure.string/split-lines file)]
    (loop [lines lines ; remaining lines 
           accu []     ; already parsed tags
           curr {}]    ; current tag being parsed
          (if lines
              (let [line (first lines)]
                (if (tag? line)
                    ; we recur after starting a new tag
                    ; if curr is empty we don't add it to the accu (e.g. first iteration)
                    (recur (next lines)
                           (add-parsed-tag accu curr)
                           {:tag line})
                    ; we're parsing values for a currentl tag
                    (recur (next lines)
                           accu
                           (add-values curr line))))
              ; if we were parsing a tag, we need to add it to the final result
              (add-parsed-tag accu curr)))))
```

I'm not quite excited about the above code, but it does the job. Given a file like:

```
Tag001
 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4
 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8
Tag002
 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4
 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8
Tag003
 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4
 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4
 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8
 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8
```

It produces the following result:

```
user=> (clojure.pprint/print-table [:tag :values] (parse-file (load-file "tags.txt")))
================================================================
:tag   | :values
================================================================
Tag001 | [[0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4] [0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8]]
Tag002 | [[1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4] [1.5 1.6 1.7 1.8]]
Tag003 | [[1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4] [1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4] [1.5 1.6 1.7 1.8] [1.5 1.6 1.7 1.8]]
================================================================
```

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I want to do! Thank you. I've wondered if there's any way of doing this without "state" but I cannot find one.

Comment: In the above code "state" is pretty much somewhat "in flux": besides the file loading in the `let` binding, everything else is implemented as pure functions. Every loop iteration just starts with new values.

Comment: I updated the code to clearly state the above point: apart from `load-file`, all others are now pure functions

Comment: There is a typo in function `load-file`: the parameter is called `path` but it is called `file` in next line `slurp file`.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done using partition-by function.  It is probably somewhat cryptic to read but   the readability can be easily increased. This function executed on my mini-mac in approx 500 milli seconds.

First I created the test data using the following function.

```
(defn write-data[fname]
   (with-open [wrtr (clojure.java.io/writer fname) ]
     (dorun 
        (for [ x (take 7500 (range)) ]
          (do
             (.write wrtr (format "Tag%010d" x))
             (.write wrtr "
                            1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4
                            1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4
                            1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8
                            1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8
                           " ))))))

(write-data "my-data.txt")

; "a b c d " will be converted to [ a b c d ]
(defn to-vec[st]
   (load-string (str "[" st "]")))


(defn my-transform[fname]
   (let [tag (atom {:tag nil})]
      (with-open [rdr (clojure.java.io/reader fname)]
         (doall 
           (into {} 
               (map 
                  (fn[xs] {(first xs) (map to-vec (rest xs))}) 
                     ( partition-by 
                          (fn[y] 
                             (if(.startsWith 
                                  (str y) "Tag") 
                                  (swap! tag assoc :tag y) @tag)) 
                       (line-seq rdr))))))))


(time (count (my-transform "my-data.txt")))
;Elapsed time: 517.23 msecs
```

Comment: Great! but the "Tag" part might not be distinguishable by "Tag"; it's just a word in a line where only clue is the line has one word.